# cleaning DOM of JS, because of livewire

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, dom

i have a project that have combination of: php(laravel) in backend AND front end of javascript+css+html.

my strategy:

1. I have an input for inserting password(input type: password).
2. I have an icon for show, password digits, when user click on that icon.
3. handle that process, by "onclick" event inside "icon" element:
   when user clicks on "eye icon", javascript changes the property of input tag, the type="password" to type="text",(user can see her/his inserted password digits ).

MY PROBLEM:

but, because of livewire property inside input tag ,after of showing password digits,
by typing more password digits, password numbers being convert to * again!

livewire property that used inside input tag: `wire:model.debounce.700ms="password"` .

I think, it is because of that:
the livewire, reloads the input tag.

Anyone knows the solution?

the div, that contains input password and eye icon(for clicking by user for show password digits):

```
<div class="o-form__field-frame o-form__field-frame--password  @error('password') has-error @enderror">
<input type="password" wire:model.debounce.700ms="password" id="password" value="{{$password}}" placeholder="PLEASE INSERT YOUR PASSWORD" class="o-form__field">
<i class='fa fa-eye hSh_eye_show_pass' onclick='showPass()'></i>
</div>
```

the function that handle that:

```
//for show pass:
function showPass(){
document.getElementById('password').type="text";
}
```

Comment: You wish to stop using JS?

Comment: @medilies this problem is also in another places in project, the conflict of livewire and JQuery and DOM.  i want to solve this conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Since `livewire` changes the input stuff you could have a second `input` of type `text` hidden and if the user clicks the other input is shown instead:

```js
// used for being able to apply the inputs values correctly..
// u can omit that this is only for making code snippet working..
let pwHidden = true

function togglePassVisibility() {
   const passVisible = document.getElementById('password-visible')
   const passHidden = document.getElementById('password-hidden')
   
   // toggle the .hidden class on both..
   
   passVisible.classList.toggle('hidden')
   passHidden.classList.toggle('hidden')
   
   // make this code snippet work since I cannot access {{$password}}
   // you can omit this..
   if(pwHidden) {
      passVisible.value = passHidden.value
   } else {
     passHidden.value = passVisible.value
   }
   
   pwHidden = !pwHidden
   
}
```

```css
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- you need ofc to pass {{$password}} as value to make it work in your environment. -->
<input type="text" class="hidden" id="password-visible"></input>
<input type="password" id="password-hidden"></input>
<button onClick="togglePassVisibility()">toggle</button>
```